# How do I create an OLEDB table with the column named "DATE"?

Tags: database, oledb, jet, dbase, dbo

We're using the Microsoft Jet OLEDB provider to insert data into a legacy system.

This system requires that we insert data by creating a DBF file, which has the format of:

```
employee Numeric (10,0),
jobcode Numeric (10,0),
date date
```

So, we are doing the following:

```
string strConnDbase = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" +
    ";Data Source = " + ruta +
    ";Extended Properties = dBASE IV" +
    ";User ID=Admin;Password=;";
```

Then, we run a command like:

```
string sql = "CREATE TABLE 20110112 ( EMPLOYEE Numeric(10,0), JOBCODE Numeric(10,0), DATE Date)";
```

Unfortunately, this "sql" statement is not running.  IE, the column named "date" is a keyword, so we cannot create the table.

We've tried escaping (single and double quotes) the column name, but that doesn't work either.

How can we build a table with the column being named "date"?

Thanks!

--
Anthony

Answer (score 3):

Try square brackets:

> CREATE TABLE 20110112 ( EMPLOYEE
>   Numeric(10,0), JOBCODE Numeric(10,0),
>   DATE [Date])

I don't have an OLEDB target handy, so this is just a guess, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a table starting with a number...  and it's really bad practice to create column names based on reserved words (date).

Just prefix with SOMEthing... even if its just "T" for "Table".

create table T20110112

Comment: Jet/ACE allows you to create a table whose name starts with a digit, or is entirely numbers. I just ran `CREATE TABLE 211123` successfully in the Access QBE, and it created the table without any problems. Whether or not it's good practice is a different question -- but it is certainly possible.